# Generating random string of size 100 or more in python

Tags: python, string, exception, random, size

When I am trying to generate random string of size 100 or more, it gives me exception...

```
msg="".join(random.sample(string.letters+string.digits,random.randint(5,100)))

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 316, in sample
    raise ValueError, "sample larger than population"
ValueError: sample larger than population
```

Can you help me and explain how can I generate a random string of size more than 100??
and also why is this exception?

Comment: depends how much higher than `100` you want to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
len(string.digits + string.letters) = 62.
```

The random.sample function does not sample with replacement, so it cannot sample more than 62 elements of this list. You might want to try an approach using list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You have 62 characters to draw from. If you try to draw longer samples, you will get the exception. You can fill up your sample space to at least the necessary length like this:

```
chars = string.letters + string.digits
sample_space = chars*((100/len(chars))+1)
msg="".join(random.sample(sample_space, random.randint(5,100)))
```

Comment: This outputs a string where each letter and digit occurs at most twice -- a possible but unusual requirement.

Comment: true, but before all characters were sampled only once, so I thought this would be a natural extension

Answer (score 1):

random.sample gives a subset.

A very unoptimized solution to your problem could be: http://codebunk.com/bunk#-IviyCJW-nmi8Lr0q_74

```
import random
import string

print ''.join([random.choice(string.letters+string.digits) for e in range(100)])
```